# php batch from while

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send all `id`s from a `while` to FPDF:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $nummer = $row[nummer];
    echo "$nummer <br>";
}
```

I am getting, for example, 5 numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I send this via JavaScript to

```
print "<a href=javascript:go_there(\"$row[nummer]\")>Print</a>";
```

then the JavaScript

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function go_there(id)
{
 var where_to= confirm("Download invoice");
 if (where_to== true)
 {
   window.location="print.php?pump=" + id;
 }
 else
 {
  window.location="";
  }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

The problem is that the file `print.php` only gets one number:

```
$pump = $_GET['pump'];
```

Usually it sends one number, and I make via print and print what I need.

Now I want one PDF file with the five numbers, so I don't have to print five times.

Hope you can help.

Comment: I think you're trying to //<![CDATA[ ...code... //]]> for your javascript.

Comment: Do you want to pass an array by GET?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$nummer = Array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $nummer[] = $row[nummer];
    print_r($nummer)
}
```